# Безопасен ли мой код для пользователей sqlite3?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite3

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start_message(message):
try:
    connect = sqlite3.connect('Users2.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            user_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            last_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            nickname TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            city TEXT)""")

    connect.commit()

    id0 = message.chat.id
    user_name0 = message.chat.first_name
    last_name0 = message.chat.last_name
    nickname0 = message.chat.username
    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT id, user_name, last_name, user_name, nickname FROM User "
        "WHERE id = ? "
        "OR user_name = ? "
        "OR last_name = ? "
        "OR nickname = ?",
        (id0, user_name0, last_name0, nickname0))
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    if data is None:
        id1 = message.chat.id
        first_name1 = message.chat.first_name
        last_name1 = message.chat.last_name
        username1 = message.chat.username
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO User VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);",
                       (id1, first_name1, last_name1, username1, ''))
        connect.commit()
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Погода")
        markup.add(btn1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет! Введи свой город, чтобы я мог предоставить тебе погоду.',
                         reply_markup=markup)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет! Я помню тебя. Если ты хочешь изменить город, введи его заново.')
    connect.close()
except sqlite3.Error as e:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Произошла ошибка при подключении к базе данных.')
except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Произошла ошибка UniqueViolation. '
                                      'Пользователь с такими данными уже существует.')
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Произошла ошибка при обращении к внешнему сервису погоды.')
except Exception as e:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Произошла непредвиденная ошибка. Попробуйте позже.')
```

Пишу телеграмм бот на telebot, делаю базу данных, можете посмотреть код и сказать безопасен ли код для пользователей, и чтобы вы добавили для безопасности кода. База данных sqlite3

Comment: Вот объясни мне пожалуйста, почему тут "cursor.execute("INSERT INTO User VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", (id1, f'{first_name1}', f'{last_name1}', f'{username1}', ''))" id1 написал хорошо, почему дальше-то начал использовать f? И, главное, для чего?

Comment: Исправил, а вообщем код безопасен?

Comment: А чего тут опасного? Пароль/почту не просишь, остальное так или иначе общедоступно если пользователь в настройках сам не запретит их получать.